# Reliable video loop for Android (Flash)

Tags: android, flash, video, air, stagevideo

What I am looking for is very simple, but I have yet to find a solution - hopefully someone here can help!

I am creating a public kiosk for an android tablet (HP Slate 17) using Flash CC-2014 Pro, and the screen saver is a short video.  All I need the video to do is loop indefinitely (and reliably) when the screen is not in use.  Seems simple enough!

I first tried the built-in Flash Pro video player with FLV and H264 files - easy enough to implement, but after a few hours the video freezes.  No good.

[I then read up on "StageVideo"](http://labs.almerblank.com/2011/09/stagevideo-as3-api-sample-code-for-flash-professional/) and how it utilizes the GPU of the tablet which should improve the performance.  Sounds promising, but every time I get a working example to loop, it freezes after a few times around (about 3 minutes).

Not sure if I am just going about the loop wrong (very possible!) or if I'm just hitting a limitation of the tablet.

For the loop portion I just added this to a function that seems to get called when the video completes:

```
_ns.dispose();
_ns.play(_videoURL);
```

Here is a link to my test project (works fine on Mac, but freezes after a few loops on Android tablet):

[Loop_freezes_on_android_files](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B10V75T3kbLnbDVIQ09OTXhWZWs/view?usp=sharing)

I am willing to entertain other methods of this entirely - as long as I get a reliable video loop on Android.

This will potentially make or break this project, so I appreciate any help!  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As your target device is an Android tablet you could try using a video native extension.

Here's one from Distriqt that I use for cycling through videos over night in a shop display.

http://airnativeextensions.com/extension/com.distriqt.MediaPlayer

Comment: Thanks - that could work!  Do you have or know of a simple Flash example that I could look at?  The site has some code bits but I'm not sure how to implement.  Would need the ability to loop the video and then toggle back to the Flash app (or make the video display underneath the app).

Comment: As a native video player it sits above your Flash layer. You wouldn't be able to display things on top of the video. Regarding a simple Flash example, it's as simple as creating MediaPlayer instance and then calling the showPlayer function of the ANE. The example code is very easy to follow and extract the parts you need to put into your own app.

Comment: I've actually gotten the FLV imported to the timeline with acceptable results (plays a little slow, but at least it's smooth).  22+ hours without freezing.  I'll still be looking into the native video though.  Thanks again!